# keep playing youtube clip in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-webbrowser, python-os

I'm trying to write a simple program to keep opening a 3 minute video in youtube over and over , and after aspecific number of pages it closes every browser then start over again
But it only run once .. Please advice

```
#Keep playing a youtube clip

import time , webbrowser , os


total_breaks = -1
start=0
def Play():
    try:
        while start != total_breaks:
            print("The {} Play of WaKra Movie started at ".format(start+1),time.ctime())

            with webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXXX") as play:
                time.sleep(5) #*60*60)
                global start
                start = start + 1
                #time.sleep(5)
                if start % 5 == 0: #every 5 pages close all browsers 
                    os.popen('TASKKILL /IM  iexplore.exe /f')
                    os.popen('TASKKILL /IM firefox.exe /f ')
                    os.popen('TASKKILL /IM chrome.exe /f ')
    except:
        print ("Some Browsers were not found")  

    print("Program terminated at",time.ctime())





Play()
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be:

```
#Keep playing a youtube clip

import time , webbrowser , os


total_breaks = -1
start=0
def play():
    try:
        while start != total_breaks:
            print("The {} Play of WaKra Movie started at ".format(start+1),time.ctime())

            with webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXXX") as play:
                time.sleep(5) #*60*60)
                global start
                start = start + 1
                #time.sleep(5)
                if start % 5 == 0: #every 5 pages close all browsers 
                    os.popen('TASKKILL /IM  iexplore.exe /f')
                    os.popen('TASKKILL /IM firefox.exe /f ')
                    os.popen('TASKKILL /IM chrome.exe /f ')
    except:
        print ("Some Browsers were not found")  

    print("Program terminated at",time.ctime())




while True:
    play()
    time.sleep(180)
```

I'm not too sure what the purpose of your program is but this will execute your `play` function (btw functions are ALWAYS in lowercase) every 3 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your response .. The purpose of this program is to increase the views of this clip as much as i could

Comment: @SkyW3lker I know im late to this, but did this actually work to increase your views?